# How to Mark CiviCRM checkbox field not required programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

```
add_filter('civicrm_buildForm','contact_mark_t_fields_optional',10,2);
function contact_mark_t_fields_optional($formName, &$form){
    if($formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_Contact'){

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $is_admin = FALSE;
        foreach($user->roles as $k =>$v){
            if($v == 'administrator'){
                $is_admin = TRUE;
            }
        }
        if ($is_admin){
            //Array ( [0] => custom_2_-1 [1] => custom_3_-1 [2] => custom_4_-1 [3] => custom_5_-1 [4] => custom_6_-1 [5] => custom_7_-1 [6] => custom_8_-1 [7] => custom_11_-1 [8] => custom_12_-1 [9] => custom_13_-1 [10] => custom_14_-1 [11] => custom_15_-1 )//
            $optional = array(
                'custom_2_-1','custom_3_-1','custom_4_-1','custom_5_-1','custom_6_-1','custom_7_-1',
                'custom_8_-1','custom_11_-1','custom_12_-1','custom_13_-1','custom_14_-1','custom_15_-1','custom_41_-1'
            );
            foreach($form->_required as $k => $v){
                if (in_array($v, $optional)){
                    unset($form->_required[$k]);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to mark a checkbox field as optional programmatically when an admin views from the admin side, but while trying to save it, it gives a "Field Required Error"

Answer (score 4):

You can use [validateForm hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) to empty the errors on the input field. Eg

```
function hook_civicrm_validateForm($formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors) {
  if (your_condition_statement) {
    $form->setElementError('field_id', NULL);
  }
}
```

Also note that as this looks like a custom field, civi also provides a UI setting to disable the `required` attribute. Screenshot from `Add/Edit custom field` form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jitendra's answer is good.  I also like the [Profile Conditionals](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond) extension by Joinery.  It only supports event and contribution pages at present, though it shouldn't be hard to extend it to work on others.